# Change elements in css with javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have these 2 elements `p.rdmore` and `ul.post-ul-more` with the property `display = none` in css.

However, on some specific pages, I want to remove these options. I did some research and came up with this code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('p.rdmore').removeClass('none').addClass('inherit');
$('ul.post-ul-more').removeClass('none').addClass('inherit');
</script>
```

I tried an if statement for javascript as well but it didn't work. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: what is happening and what do you expect it should work...you get error in console?

Comment: Are `none` and `inherit` classes on these elements?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `css()` method to change CSS properties such as display. Try the following:

```
$('p.rdmore').css("display", "inherit");
$('ul.post-ul-more').css("display", "inherit");
```

`.css()` changes the CSS of an element by jQuery. Read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp).

If I wanted to change the background, I would just do this:

```
$("element-right-here").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

The parameters are `.css(propertyName, propertyValue)` or `.css(propertyName)`. The latter will return the actual value at the point it is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show the elements you can use jQuery's methods for that.

```
$('p.rdmore').show()
```

And if you want to hide it:

```
$('p.rdmore').hide()
```

Or if you are going to go back and forth you can have one event that toggles it:

```
$('p.rdmore').toggle()
```

in the last case jQuery will figure out for you if its visible or not and then reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code which will be more efficient.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
$('p.rdmore').toggleClass('none inherit');
$('ul.post-ul-more').toggleClass('none inherit');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely try it.